# Accessing a passed Object with Express and Axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

In the client side I have :

```
handleChangeSave(values, id) {
    axios.post('/api/users/change' + id, JSON.stringify(values))
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp.data);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

On the server side I am trying to query for the object and it is coming back empty when it is really not.

```
router.post('/users/change:id', (req, res) => {
  User.findById({ '_id': req.params.id }, (err, user) => {
      if(err) return res.status(500).send(err);
      let Values = req.query;
      console.log(Values); // returns {}
  })
});
```

Comment: Typing error `/users/change/:id` , and use `body-parser` to get `req.body` as post body

Comment: @MukeshSharma Idk if it matters, but please submit as an answer and I will mark it as correct. Thank You!